# Exception handling without try block

Tags: java

I think this is correct... When an exception occurs an object of the exception class is thrown and if we dont use a try or catch block, then the object goes to the JVM. 
                                                                                   **My question is why is the try block necessary, why wouldn't a catch block be good enough since the exception object is not created in the try block?** I know that java requires you to use a try block to test the code in which the exception might occur, but was wondering if the exception object is created either way, then why couldn't a catch block been sufficient enough. This question is different from other exception handling questions in that it doesn't appear anyone has asked about needing to have the try block specifically.

Comment: Please provide sample code for what you're proposing. I suspect the problem will become obvious to you.

Comment: What do you mean by "the JVM handles it"? Exiting with an error message may be acceptable in development, but I wouldn't say the error has been *handled*.

Comment: I didn't necessarily mean it is handled more so that the exception object was created without the try block

Comment: @R2D2 what if you want to do `try { /* code */ } catch (Exception e) {} /* other code which will propagate if it throws */ try { /* code 3 */ } catch (Exception e) {}`

Comment: I don't understand why you insist on the exception object being created. It is. `try` doesn't exist in order to ensure it's creation.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the try block is there for the creation of the exception object. Thanks for all of the answers I appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try { }` portion indicates the section of code the `catch { }` block is protecting.

```
void test() {
    do_something();          // Not covered
    try {
       something_fixable();  // Covered
    } catch (InvalidStateException ex) {
       do_recovery_for_fixable_thing();
    }
}
```

Without the `try { }` block, the `catch { }` block might try to catch an exception other than the one it can handle.

Even if the exception thrown by `do_something()` is the same kind of exception, an `InvalidStateException`, the recovery code won't handle it; it isn't supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you had the following

```
doSomething(); // throws Exception1
doNothing();   // throws Exception2 which extends Exception1
catch(Exception 1 ex){   // handle exception  }
```

To what does the catch block apply?   Will it act only if an exception is thrown in `doNothing()`?  Or will it also apply to the call to `doSomething()`.  Or perhaps it will only apply to `doSomething()` and not `doNothing()`, which throws Exception2.

There is precedent for the omission of brackets.   For example consider the next 2 groups of code.

```
int i;
for( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) 
   System.out.println("hello World" + i);
```

and

```
int i;
for( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) 
{
   System.out.println("hello World" + i);
}
```

Here the for statement is understood to act either on the next bracketed block or next single line of code.

So I suppose it might have been possible to have catch statements work on the previous statement or on the previous block.   But that is just syntactic sugar, right?   There is no functionality that you lose by requiring a try block.